# "No such file or directory" ODOO10

Tags: odoo-10

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_attachment.py", line 100, in _file_read
    r = open(full_path,'rb').read().encode('base64')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/var/lib/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/coverpr1/f3/f3f11e52a3ead336749157f46e1c8d8a07de8b61'
```

Comment: please provide bit more information so that someone can help you fast

Comment: delete all records from ir.attachment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have solved it by deleting all the records from `ir_attachment` table. Use the query below to solve the problem.

```sql
DELETE FROM ir_attachment;
```

Comment: Hi! I have a similar problem and I want to try this solution that it worked for you but I do not know how to do it. I use Docker and it is Odoo 14. Where and how I can run this command?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE url LIKE '/web/content/%';
```

Comment: +1. Targeting 'url' seems to have cured the website display problems that were a companion symptom of "No such file or directory". Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with Linux, you can get all records from logfile:

```
grep 'No such file or directory'  /var/log/odoo/odoo.log| cut -d'/' -f 10 | sort| uniq > /tmp/2delete.txt
```

And open the file and create an SQL syntax for each line found.

Example

```
DELETE FROM ir_attachment WHERE store_fname LIKE '%ff3fb425a0e573436f30d1377e3e74ba095b3a4d%';
```

Next, execute all SQL sentences in your database.

I my case:

```
psql myOdooDB -U odooUser < /tmp/2deleteSQLFormat.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete all the records from ir_attachment then it will delete the attachment from all modules where ever we have attached our documents.